# Using xrdp to tunnel to an existing X server

Tags: xvfb, xserver, xrdp

I'm working with an existing tool that requires a RDP connection to a Ubuntu server.

The application runs in a **xvfb** display server (using the command *xvfb-run*) on a specific *DISPLAY* on the server.

I've installed **xrdp** to open a connection to this Xserver, however each time i initiate a new connection, the **xrdp-sesman** (which is the session manager of the *xrdp* tool) opens a new **Xvnc server** on a different DISPLAY.

My goal would be to tunnel the xrdp connection to the specific DISPLAY where my application is, does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v` in `xvfb` means that you are using a virtual display.

You probably want to look into something like [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/).

> x11vnc allows one to view remotely and interact with real X displays (i.e. a display corresponding to a physical monitor, keyboard, and mouse) with any VNC viewer. In this way it plays the role for Unix/X11 that WinVNC plays for Windows.

[AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567371/connect-using-windows-rdp) has the guide for setup as such (quoted below)

> You'll need xrdp together with x11vnc if you want remote access to your Unity desktop.
>
> First, install xrdp and x11vnc: `apt-get install xrdp x11vnc` (or whatever your distribution equivalent is)
>
> Then edit `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` and make sure it contains at least the
>   following:

```
 [globals]
 bitmap_cache=yes 
 bitmap_compression=yes 
 port=3389
 crypt_level=high 
 channel_code=1 
 max_bpp=24


 [xrdp1]
 name=Remote Desktop
 lib=libvnc.so
 username=ask
 password=ask
 ip=127.0.0.1
 port=5900
```

> Restart xrdp for the changes to take effect:
>
> `/etc/init.d/xrdp restart`
>
> Now open up a terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and set up a VNC password
>   (you don't want to leave wide open access to your desktop from the
>   internet):
>
> `x11vnc -usepw`
>
> You'll be prompted to set up a password, that will be used for RDP
>   authentication.
>
> The last step is to start x11vnc. There are tons of options that you
>   can use, but here is an example to get you started (run this in the
>   same terminal window you just opened):

```
x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -display WAIT:0 -reopen -nevershared
-forever -wirecopyrect always -scrollcopyrect always -norepeat -1 -xkb -capslock -skip_keycodes 187,188 -bg -o ~/x11vnc.log &
```

> The & at the end will leave x11vnc running the background, so you can
>   close the terminal window and leave it running.
>
> You'll need to add this command to your startup scripts if you want
>   x11vnc to run automatically after a reboot.

Comment: Hello, actually i've already tried this solution, and the problem is the responsive-ness of the window, when i tunnel, the x11vnc doesn't resize with the size of my client (i know it may seem minor but it actually causes border effects on the tool opening the RDP connection)

Comment: @SimHm unfortunately that statement looks correct. As you are using x11vnc you are really connecting via VNC, therefore I doubt that advantages of the RDP protocol (such as compression or better responsiveness) won't be available. I am looking for options too.

Comment: It would be worth it to investigate the combination of xvfb + xorgxrdp + xrdp